# Solving a logarithmic function using Accord.net

Tags: regression, curve-fitting, accord.net

I have a set of data `(X,Y)` and I want to make a custom regression model from those data.
My custom regression model is `Y=a(X-b)^c`.
Can I use Accord.net to solve it?
My goal is finding the values of `a`,`b`, and `c`?

Thank you for you kindly help

Comment: If you can use an online solution, a fitter for this equation is on my zunzun.com web site here: http://zunzun.com/Equation/2/Power/X%20Shifted%20Power/

Comment: Thank you @JamesPhillips for your suggestion. I have checked your tool. That is a great tool. But I want to make it in .NET code. So, I use Accord.net and VB.net. is there another suggestion?

Comment: To answer your question, I gave up C# for Python many years ago, and can only recommend internet searches regarding other suggestions.